# Get OData method - Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Trying to test the following

```
// GET: odata/API_INSTANCE
    [EnableQuery]
    public SingleResult<API_INSTANCE> GetAPI_INSTANCE([FromODataUri] Guid key)
    {
     return SingleResult.Create(db.API_FIRM_LINK.Where(m => m.ApiFirmLinkId == key).Select(m => m.API_INSTANCE));
    }
```

Here is what I have so far : not sure how to call ODATA, GUID KEY. I asked a similar question already related to this

```
   public void GetAPI_INSTANCETest()
    {

        ////Arrange
        API_FIRM_LINKController controller = new API_FIRM_LINKController();
        ////ACT
        controller.GetAPI_INSTANCE();
        SingleResult result = controller.GetAPI_INSTANCE() as SingleResult;
        ////Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Console.Write(result);

    }
}
```